# Angular 10 - AWS Amplify Auth - AuthError - Error: Amplify has not been configured correctly

Tags: angular, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools, aws-amplify-sdk-js

Deployed SPA application on to AWS Amplify, and enabled Auth. getting below error

[image]

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^10.0.14",
        "@angular/cdk": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/common": "^10.0.14",
        "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.14",
        "@angular/core": "^10.0.14",
        "@angular/flex-layout": "^10.0.0-beta.32",
        "@angular/forms": "^10.0.14",
        "@angular/material": "^8.1.1",
        "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "8.2.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^10.0.14",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^10.0.14",
        "@angular/router": "^10.0.14",
        "@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^0.2.15",
        "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.5.4",
        "aws-amplify": "^3.0.24",
        "brace": "^0.11.1",
        "core-js": "^3.1.4",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
        "fs-extra": "^9.0.0",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "jasmine-reporters": "^2.3.2",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
        "moment": "2.24.0",
        "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
        "ngx-dropzone": "^2.1.1",
        "oidc-client": "^1.9.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
        "protractor-html-reporter-2": "^1.0.4",
        "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",
        "rxjs": "^6.6.2",
        "uuid": "^3.3.3",
        "web-animations-js": "2.3.2",
        "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.8",
        "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.1000.8",
        "@angular/cli": "~10.0.8",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.14",
        "@angular/language-service": "^10.0.14",
        "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.13",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.6",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.29",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.136",
        "@types/node": "^12.6.9",
        "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
        "karma": "~4.2.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.0.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
        "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
        "ng-packagr": "^10.1.0",
        "protractor": "~5.4.2",
        "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
        "tsickle": "^0.38.1",
        "tslib": "^2.0.1",
        "tslint": "~5.18.0",
        "typescript": "~3.9.7",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.3.2"
    }
```

abcd.module.ts

[image]

main.ts

[image]

Can i get any help!!

Comment: your `awsconfig` should have region,access key and secret key . Check the content.

Comment: Could you please give reference code

Comment: instead of the photo can you share the code ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my bad.
when i renamed "aws-exports.js" to "aws-exports.ts" the content inside "aws-exports.ts" file as below

```
const awsmobile = {
"aws_project_region": "ap-southeast-2"
};
export default awsmobile;
```

this is wrong(above one). it should be as below

```
const awsmobile = {
  "aws_project_region": "ap-southeast-2",
  "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "ap-southeast-2:a3346e2c-xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx",
  "aws_cognito_region": "ap-southeast-2",
  "aws_user_pools_id": "ap-southeast-xxxxxxxxx",
  "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "oauth": {}
};
```

Comment: I just got this error after a update.  I hadn't touched my aws-exports.js file.  It works local, but when I `ng build` the dist is broken.